# equivalent of "str()" (describes dataframe) for a spark table using sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

My question boilds down to: what is the Sparklyr equivalent to the `str` R command?

I am opening a large table (from a file), call it `my_table`, in Spark, from R using the Sparklyr package.

How can describe the table? Column names and types, a few examples, etc.

Apologies in advance for what must be a very basic question but I did search for it, and checked Rstudio's Sparklyr Cheatsheet and did not find the answer.

Comment: for schema, `df.printSchema`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use the `mtcars` dataset and move it to a local spark instance for example purposes:

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
tbl_cars <- dplyr::copy_to(sc, mtcars, "mtcars")
```

Now you have many options, here are 2 of them, each slightly different - choose based on your needs:

1.Collect the first row into R (now it is a standard R data frame) and look at str:

```
 str(tbl_cars %>% head(1) %>% collect())
```

2.Invoke the `schema` method and look at the result:

```
spark_dataframe(tbl_cars) %>% invoke("schema")
```

This will give something like:

```
StructType(StructField(mpg,DoubleType,true), StructField(cyl,DoubleType,true), StructField(disp,DoubleType,true), StructField(hp,DoubleType,true), StructField(drat,DoubleType,true), StructField(wt,DoubleType,true), StructField(qsec,DoubleType,true), StructField(vs,DoubleType,true), StructField(am,DoubleType,true), StructField(gear,DoubleType,true), StructField(carb,DoubleType,true))
```